# Mapping nodeid to embedded vectors in neo4j

Tags: machine-learning, neo4j, nodes

I have uploaded a adjacency matrix into neo4j and used node2vec to get the embedded vectors.I intend to use this on a machine learning classification problem where I have to add the output class as the last column to this embedded vectors,but I am not sure if the embedded vectors I obtained are in the same order(row-wise) as in the adjacency matrix.How do I make sure of this.Any help here would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show any code what exactly are you trying and in which environment

Comment: with 600 as noOfNodes
unwind range(1,noOfNodes) as index
create(n:Node{id: index})
load csv from "file:///adjmat.csv" as line
with line skip 1
with line, toInteger(line[0]) as startNode, size(line)-1 as noOfRelationships
match(n:Node{id: startNode})
unwind range(1, noOfRelationships) as index
 I load my adjacency matrix in neo4j and then  i call a projected graph 'all', use node2vec  CALL gds.beta.node2vec.stream("all", {walksPerNode: 2, embeddingDimension: 10}).getting the out put nodeid and embedded vectors(600*10) .now i need to map this node id with rows in adjmatrix(600*600)

Answer (score 0):

Embeddings are unrelated to the node-ids in the graph.

They are just a list/vectors of floating point numbers (of the width you specified or the default width) that represent the "essence" of each node based on it's attributes and contextual neighborhood.